# c# Query sqlite database, get back a data with a type

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am encountering some issues when it comes to getting back data from my c# database query
this is my code for the query :

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Cryptomoney
{
    class DataClass
    {
        private static SQLiteConnection sqlite;

        public DataClass()
        {
            sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= DataCrypto.sqlite3;Version=3;New=False;");
        }

        public SQLiteDataReader SelectQuery(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlite.Open();  //Initiate connection to the db
                SQLiteCommand sqlComm = sqlite.CreateCommand();
                sqlComm.CommandText = query;
                SQLiteDataReader r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
                sqlite.Close();
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            sqlite.Close();
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code with the sql :

```cs
var b = dataClass.SelectQuery("SELECT PercChange1h FROM DataCrypt WHERE ID = 1");
```

I want b to be a float, the same type as PercChange1h is in my database but I only get "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader".

I already tried :

```cs
  var b = (float)dataClass.SelectQuery("SELECT PercChange1h FROM DataCrypt WHERE ID = 1")["PercChange1h"]
```

which returns an error "row does not exist". And all other types of casts do not work ((int), ToString())

My code is nearly the same with create or ALTER or INSERT and it works just fine (but I do not have to get back data"

```cs
   var cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
   cmd = sqlite.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = query;  //set the passed query
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Do you know how I could get back a type like string or float from my sqlite db with c# ?
(this is my first question ever so if there is not enough data, I am here to answer)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Erm, you need to actually read data from the data reader `while(reader.Read()) { someListOfData.Add((float)reader["b"])); }` You don't return the data reader from the function, just the list that you've read. I'd advise you not to use a generic function for this, write a new function for each query. But if you only want one value, you can just do `(float)cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Then cast to double first `(float)(double)whatever`. The `double` data type means it is double-precision, a 64-bit float as opposed to 32-bit. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types You really need to learn how basic C# types work

Comment: yes it worked, I will follow the link , Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this

```
    public object QueryScalarValue(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlite.Open();  //Initiate connection to the db
            using(SQLiteCommand sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand(query, sqlite))
            return sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlite.Close();
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Then you simply cast the result

```
var b = (double)dataClass.SelectQuery("SELECT PercChange1h FROM DataCrypt WHERE ID = 1");
```